# Python logging output format with .conf

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to edit the output format in my .conf file:

```
... 
[formatter_formatter]
format=Time: &(asctime)s | File: %(name)s | %(levelname)s | \n Message: %(message)s
datefmt=%H:%M:%S
```

When I add `\n` in the format, it dos not output a new line. It just outputs:

```
INFO | FILE: application.main | TIME: 10:17:16 | MESSAGE: \n Starting the application!
```

But it does work when I use the `logging.basicConfig()`:

```
FORMAT = "&(asctime)s | File: %(name)s | %(levelname)s | \n Message: %(message)s" 
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
```

Has someone an idea how i can add a new line in the .conf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by myself. Quite simple:

```
... 
[formatter_formatter]
format=%(levelname)s | FILE: %(name)s | TIME: %(asctime)s:
    MESSAGE: %(message)s
datefmt=%H:%M:%S
```

If you want to add a new line you just need to indent the content with 4 spaces. Then the output will be like this:

```
INFO | FILE: application.main | TIME: 10:17:16:
MESSAGE: Starting the application!
```